# Display .png image with Tkinter and PIL

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I try to display .png file in Tkinter Label, but in effect I get just empty space in place where image should be displayed. It's very simple code and i have no idea what is wrong.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

image = Image.open('image.png')
display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image))

label = Label(root, image=display)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

You're calling Image.open() twice. It's enough to call it once. Use:

```
display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

instead of:

```
display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image))
```

Comment: My mistake, I tried to resolve this problem on my own and I made some mess in code. I corrected it, but it doesn't change anything. I still see only empty window.

Comment: Repost your current code, so we don't have to guess what the 'mess' is?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this problem in this way:

```
image = Image.open('image.png').convert("RGB")
```

I'm not sure if it's correct, but it works.

Comment: and how does the line that starts with 'display=' now looks?

Comment: now it looks:
`image = Image.open('image.png').convert("RGB")`  
`display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)`

Answer (score 1):

for me it only worked after adding the line: `label.image= display`

Whole solution for your problem:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

image = Image.open('image.png')
display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image))

label = Label(root, image=display)
label.image = display
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The label.image = display line prevents garbage collection from wiping your variable.