# TKinter fails to display large PNG image if it's not RGB

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have some Tkinter code that displays an image in the middle of a canvas:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        width=1280
        height=720

        self.testImage = Image.open("Drawing.png")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root,height=height,width=width,bg='blue')

        # from some SO post
        basewidth=720
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(self.testImage.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(self.testImage.size[1])*float(wpercent)))

        self.testImage = self.testImage.resize((400,400),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.testImage)
        self.canvas.create_image(width/2,height/2,image=self.photo)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

This displays my image in the middle of a blue 1280x720 canvas. If I change the resize to:

```
        self.testImage = self.testImage.resize((500,500),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I get an empty blue 1280x720 canvas. I was working towards getting the image to scale to fill the canvas, but it's disappearing if my image is any size over 400x400 seems like. My base image file is a 3000x2000 or so PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649892/display-png-image-with-tkinter-and-pil).

Simply changing:
`self.testImage = Image.open("Drawing.png")`
to
`self.testImage = Image.open("Drawing.png").convert("RGB")`
Allows this to run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: You use the `Canvas widht/height` for `create_image(...`, try the following:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    width=1280; height=720
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root,height=height,width=width,bg='blue')

    self.testImage = Image.open("Drawing.png")
    self.testImage = self.testImage.resize((width,height),PIL.Image.BILINEAR)

    width,height=self.testImage.size
    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.testImage)
    self.canvas.create_image(width/2,height/2,image=self.photo)
    self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Consider this Example: [viewing-large-images-with-scrollbars-using-python-tk-and-pil/](http://www.swharden.com/wp/2010-03-03-viewing-large-images-with-scrollbars-using-python-tk-and-pil/)

---

> **Comment**: ... with BILINEAR I can scale ... up to 800x720 before it disappears

Think about to `down sample` your Image to *1280x720* Outside of your Script, instead of `down sizeing` Inside the Script.

---

According to the [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) Documentation, Filter `PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS` is not supported.

> ```
> Image.resize(size, resample=0)
> ```
>
> Returns a resized copy of this image.
>   Parameters:
>
> size – The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple: (width, height).
>   resample – An optional resampling filter.
>   This can be one of PIL.Image.NEAREST, PIL.Image.BOX, PIL.Image.BILINEAR, PIL.Image.HAMMING, PIL.Image.BICUBIC or PIL.Image.LANCZOS.
>   If omitted, or if the image has mode “1” or “P”, it is set PIL.Image.NEAREST.
>   See: [Filters](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-filters).

Comment: If I replace that statement the image does not display on the canvas at any size.

Comment: If I replace `ANTIALIAS`  with `BILINEAR` I can scale the image up to 800x720 before it disappears though, so you may be on to something.

Comment: The purpose of my program is to process arbitrary photos for a user, so displaying potentially large images is core functionality.

Comment: Using `Image.show()` displays the image just fine, resized to any size, or not resized at all.

Comment: I tried placing a large GIF image on the canvas without going through the `Image` class, just using `ImageTk` and it works as expected.

Comment: The issue must be somewhere in the interaction between PIL and Tkinter...

Comment: Tried resetting the width and height, no difference, tried placing at 0,0 and setting `anchor='nw'`, still doesn't display with `BILINEAR` over 800x800, `LANZCOS` over like 100x100 or `NEAREST` over 400x400. I think I'm hitting a limit somewhere.

Comment: Turns out my PNG is only 1600x1000 and 141kb so shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: python 3.6.1, tkinter 8.5, pillow ~~ 1.1.7 ~~ 4.2.1

Comment: Apparently strikethrough isn't supported, but I used the wrong command, Pillow is version 4.2.1 not 1.1.7

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Strelok: Update `tkinter` to **Tcl/Tk 8.6.6 Jul 27, 2016 **.